# How to check if a XML node is empty from SSIS?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ssis, xquery

I have a SSIS package that proccess some XML with XSLT and the result is a CSV file, but sometimes some nodes of the XML are empty and I need to prevent the creation of an empty CSV.

Is it possible to validate the XML before the XSLT Process task?

I'm thinking in a XPath validation but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If by *validation*  you mean checking that that a node actually contains text to extract, then the simplest validation is a node test on string-length. You can do this during the actual transformation to CSV, so you simply skip rows that would be partially populated.

I have no idea what your XML source is, but given an input structure like this:

```
<test.to.csv>
    <item>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>32</b>
        <c>blah</c>
    </item>
    <item>
        <a>foo</a>
        <b>33</b>
        <c/>
    </item>
</test.to.csv>
```

... then a template rule like this should suffice:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="a[text()] and b[text()] and c[text()]">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() lt last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the node test on string-length.

This outputs:

```
foo,32,blah
```

Comment: "*the simplest validation is a node test on string-length.*" Actually, the simplest test is for the existence of a child text node - for example, as `<xsl:template match="item[text()]">`.

Comment: Quite right, and I'll modify the sample to reflect this simpler node-test